# How to check an HtmlElement exists in an HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, html, browser, match

C# - I am working with a web-browser control as my application requires a UI for web pages, It allows editing of Html files and as a project, will search all project pages for the containing element that is currently selected.

Choosing to view the Outer Html of any given element looks fine, but any more than 1 attribute and the order of the text is reversed as below:

From:

```
<a href="Misc/coralifeaqualight.comcoralife-bulbs/" class="link-post-on-header">Coralife Bulbs</a>
```

to:

```
<a class="link-post-on-header" href="Misc/coralifeaqualight.comcoralife-bulbs/">Coralife Bulbs</a>
```

So I need to know, is there a way to stop HtmlElements from reversing their content so it still matches the Html source when viewed, or is there a fast way to check an entire HtmlDocument(System.Windows.Forms) for an given HtmlElement so it wont matter?

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't win a beauty award but... 
It could do the job.. If i understand you well, you'd like to check if a html element exists in 2 documents? Mayby verifying the attributes will do the job?

```
static bool FindElementsByClassAndHref(HtmlDocument doc, string className, string href)
{
  foreach (HtmlElement e in doc.All)
    if (e.GetAttribute("className") == className && e.GetAttribute("href") == href)
      return true;
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping to not have to go back to method, I did compare elements like this some time ago, grabbing the most common and then so long as they all matched, even the null entries - it must be the same element. Sigh - If the text of an element didn't change when converted to an HtmlElement from DocumentText I wouldn't have this damn issue lol.

Comment: you already can find the 2 instances of the link?

Mayby you can check on the char count of the url.. or something like that.. 
But i wouldn't do that.. your not very sure of your case then..